# Why my kFormater is doesnt add any format

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

soo i want to make like is formated like 1.2k, 5.1M etc. but its doesnt add "k" or "M"

`" onclick="handleLike('')" class="btn btn-primary" style="background: #F2BE22;">
 "><%= element.like %>

```
            <script>
              function kFormatter(num) {
                return Math.abs(num) > 999 ? Math.sign(num) * ((Math.abs(num) / 1000).toFixed(1)) + 'k' : Math.sign(num) * Math.abs(num);
              }
            
              window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                var likeCountElements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="likeCount"]');
                likeCountElements.forEach(function(element) {
                  element.textContent = kFormatter(currentLikes);
                });
              });
            </script>`
```

its just format the num but not give the "k"

I want to make it like youtube like when its thousand it will format it to something like 1.2k

Comment: What's the input parameter? Can you check it?